# Show that every Frobenius group contains a solvable Frobenius subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have trouble in the problem ''Show that every Frobenius group contains a solvable Frobenius subgroup."

My idea is to take a subgroup of order $p$ in the Frobenius complement and show there is a solvable subgroup of Frobenius kernel which is invariant under it. But I failed.

Comment: There is a (nontrivial) theorem due to Thompson that says that  the Frobenius kernel is nilpotent (at least for finite groups). The result follows from that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can avoid using Thompson's result on the nilpotency of the Frobenius kernel as follows. As you suggested, let $g$ be an element of prime order $p$ in a Frobenius complement, let $K$ be the Frobenius kernel, and let $H$ be the subgroup $\langle K,g \rangle$ of $G$ - so $|H| = |K|p$.

Since $p$ divides $|K|-1$, it cannot divide $|K|$. Let $q$ be a prime dividing $K$ and let $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(K)$. By the Frattini Argument, $p$  divides $|N_H(Q)|$ and, since $\langle g \rangle \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$, we have $g^h \in N_H(Q)$ for some $h \in H$ and $\langle Q,g^h \rangle$ is a solvable Frobenius subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!